# She went around in about a hundred and seventy, for nine holes - meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I read the "Catcher in the rye" and I found it difficult book for not native reader (Compared to for example Steve Jobs biography.

There is a lot of guessing what the author means by particular sentence.

Context :

> "Her mother belonged to the same club we did," I said. "I used to
>   caddy once in a while, just to make some dough. I caddy'd for her
>   mother a couple of times. She went around in about a hundred and
>   seventy, for nine holes."

I wonder what the main character refer to by :

> She went around in about a hundred and seventy, for nine holes.

Are the numbers refer to numbers in golf?

What does :

> "Go around"

means here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the mother played nine holes of golf [half the course] and took about 170 strokes. That's about four times as many as a low-handicap player.

*Go around* means to progress along a defined path back to your starting point — as *around a circle, around a course*.

Comment: Andrew, congratulations! I see you are a 30k-user now. Excellent work. But have you gained the custodian badge too?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Thanks, but -- not quite yet (29970). And yes: seven times.

Comment: What do you mean by "half the course". Is there any standard course in golf that takes 18 holes ?

Comment: [All standard courses are eighteen holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_course).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, you've also used golf word: "low-handicap", meaning "good player" that gets around 60-75 strokes to complete whole 18 - hole course. Right ?

Comment: 60-75 is a very good player for 18 holes, I think.

Comment: Courses are set out so that after playing all 18 holes you arrive back at the clubhouse, hence 'a round of golf'.

Comment: @bluesm: Actually, 60 is almost unreachable. For most courses, par is 70 to 72. Even the best golfers in the world rarely get much under 66 in a round.

Comment: So we conclude that 170 strokes for 9 holes is very far from the "best golfer" category.

Comment: @GEdgar: Actually, anything much over 120 is considered quite amateur, and that's for 18 holes. 170 for 9 is so bad that I'm assuming that at least a modicum of humor is intended. It's a score many would beat even on their first very first outing on a golf course.